# Update tabPanel content with selection in Sidebar control | Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I am making a very simple Shiny app, where I want to update `tabPanel` content with whatever is selected in `sidebarMenu`, no matter which tab is selected. Following is my sample code. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
library(shinydashboard)

siderbar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    # Add buttons to choose the way you want to select your data
    radioButtons("select_by", "Select by:",
                 c("Food Type" = "Food",
                   "Gym Type" = "Gym",
                   "TV show" = "TV"))
  )   
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    tabBox(
      side = "right",
      selected = "Tab3",
      tabPanel("Tab1", "Tab content 1"),
      tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2"),
      tabPanel("Tab3", "Tab content 3")
    )
  ),
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"),
    siderbar,
    body
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    getReaction <- reactive(input$select_by)
    
    # The currently selected tab from the first box
    output$tabset1Selected <- renderText({
      getReaction
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't define any `textOutput`. Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

siderbar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    # Add buttons to choose the way you want to select your data
    radioButtons("select_by", "Select by:",
                 c("Food Type" = "Food",
                   "Gym Type" = "Gym",
                   "TV show" = "TV"))
  )   
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    tabBox(
      side = "right",
      selected = "Tab3",
      tabPanel("Tab1", "Tab content 1", textOutput("tabset1Selected")),
      tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2", textOutput("tabset2Selected")),
      tabPanel("Tab3", "Tab content 3", textOutput("tabset3Selected"))
    )
  ),
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"),
    siderbar,
    body
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    # The currently selected tab from the first box
    output$tabset1Selected <- output$tabset2Selected <- output$tabset3Selected <- renderText({
      input$select_by
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem. I have a follow-up question on this solution, can you please have a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70567254/delay-in-tabpanel-content-update-when-sidebar-control-updated